# how to crawl page as fast as possible?

Tags: python, web-crawler, time-to-first-byte

i want to crawl google result using python, but the crawler is slow. i want to reduce `time-to-first-byte`. 
when i use google in my browser timing is as bellow:
[image]

when i use `requests` to get google in my website timing is as bellow:
[image]

and locally i get google this way:
[image]

how can i load google progressive and reduce `time-to-first-byte`?

Comment: You can try removing any DNS delay. Replace the domain name with the server's IP and set the `host` header to the domain. But... you will eventually be welcomed by a CAPTCHA.